# Vue2: JSON object using emit not working?

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass a JSON object from child component to parent, but something not working as I expect:

when I try to read the propriety on the parent javascript function it returns me `[Object object]`

I'm not figuring out how to read the entire JSON, consider that in the child component the JSON is as I expect.

**here my child component function (inside METHODS):**

```
sendAllSteps : function(uscita){
//"uscita" is the json object
    this.$emit('mandapreventivo',{uscita});
return;     
},
```

**in index.html**

```
                <lista-percorso :selezionati="il_tuo_percorso"
                            v-on:removeall="pathlengthTozero()"
                            v-on:vediservizi="mostraPercorso2"
                            v-on:rimuoviprezzo="priceremove($event)"
                            v-on:rimuoviprezzoparent="priceparentremove($event)"
                            v-on:mandapreventivo="postaTutto($event)"
                            ></lista-percorso>
```

**in main.js**

```
postaTutto : function({uscita}){
    console.log("dati uscita "+ `${uscita}`);
    console.log(this.modello.lineaGialla);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(`${uscita}`));

    var exit = `${uscita}`;
    alert(exit);
    alert(exit[0].length);
    alert(JSON.stringify(`${uscita}`));
    var exit2 = exit.toString(`${uscita}`);
    alert(exit2);
//this return to me [object Object]

    this.isLoading=true;
    var config = {dataType: "jsonp"};

    axios.post(
            'url.something',
            //invia,
            {'serviziSelezionati':`${uscita}`},
            config          
        )
      .then(function (response) {
        this.isLoading=false;
        var risposta = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        console.log(risposta);
        alert("grazie per aver compilato il form!");
        return;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        this.isLoading=false;
        console.log(error);
        alert("qualcosa è andato storto");
        return;
      });

},
```

Now, I really don't know how to see the ${uscita} object, When I post the data there is a PHP compiler who interpret JSON and assign value that seems just blank

Does somebody already had this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
var exit = `${uscita}`;
```

This code takes the `uscita` object and basically executes `toString()` on it, which results in "[object Object]".

This line:

```
var exit2 = exit.toString(`${uscita}`);
```

doesn't to anything. `exit` is already a string, and `toString()` doesn't take any arguments. The result is the same value in `exit`, "[object Object]".

"[object Object]" is the result *anytime* you do a `toString()` on an object.

I expect what you *want* is to submit the `uscita` object, which you should be able to do like this:

```
axios.post("url.something", {'serviziSelezionati': uscita}, config)
```

Axios will convert the data to JSON as needed.

Additionally, you are doing some unnecessary destructuring. Just pass the `uscita` object:

```
this.$emit('mandapreventivo', uscita)
```

which means your method can just be

```
postaTutto : function(uscita){...}
```